# Will Select array via Postgresql index wil be faster if array is sorted?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, query-optimization

I got a table that contains about 180 millions lines and I am constantly selecting from it with this SQL:

```
Select table. Ids from table
Where ids = any(string_to_array(array['1','3','4','10']) 
      and date < '2023.12.11 '
```

I got a B-tree index on the table. Ids, but the array in sending could be up to 100 items.

So here is the question, will it affect productivity if I sort this array before sending to Select and why?

Thank you

I try explain analyze but since Postgres cash all data it hard to compare results.

Comment: PostgreSQL sorts it for you before or as a part of the comparison. Attach table DDL and output of this query with `explain (analyze, buffers)` added before it to get reliable recommendations. If you often add the condition on date, you could consider multi-column index that also covers the date. Do you really only select the `Id` field? Are you giving it array of `text` because the `Id` field is also `text`?

Comment: When you tried it with your data, your version, and your hardware, what did you find?

Comment: Nested Loop (cost=0.14..909.54 rows=103 width=13) (actual time=0.122..0.123 rows=0 loops=1)
  Join Filter: ((t_over_agr_4135.cur_ovr_lifo_start_dt <= (unnest('{2023-09-07}'::date[]))) AND ((t_over_agr_4135.cur_ovr_all_ccy_amt)::double precision > (unnest('{1000}'::double precision[]))) AND ((t_over_agr_4135.appl_num)::text = ANY (string_to_array(((unnest('{1ツ2ツ3ツ4ツ5}'::character varying[])))::text, 'ツ'::text))))
  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 20
  Buffers: shared hit=2
  ->  Append  (cost=0.14..6.57 rows=19 width=18) (actual time=0.023..0.036 rows=20 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=2

Comment: ->  Index Scan using t_over_agr_4135_appl_num_idx on t_over_agr_4135  (cost=0.14..6.47 rows=19 width=18) (actual time=0.023..0.034 rows=20 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (appl_num IS NOT NULL)
              Buffers: shared hit=2
  ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..5.03 rows=1000 width=48) (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=1 loops=20)
        ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=1 loops=20)
Planning Time: 0.937 ms
Execution Time: 0.314 ms

Comment: That's result of explain analyze of my query, but it a bit complicated because we use our own DSL for queries and than it transforms to SQL

Comment: @Zegarek thank you! Maybe you know where in Postgres documentation I could read about this sorting?